# Different output DOC, Excel and PDF in Jasper?

Tags: java, excel, pdf, jasper-reports

**Update**

When I use `Jasper Report 5.6` version, the printed files(`DOC, Excel and PDF`) are different format as below images. In `DOC` and `Excel`, there missing things like `subtotal`and `No. Column ($V{REPORT_COUNT})`.

PDF (Correct Outpt)

[image]

DOC (Incorrect Outpt)

[image]

EXCEL (Incorrect Outpt)

[image]

5.6 Code as below

```
/*PDF File Generation */
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print, pdf_filePath);

/*Excel File Generation */
JRXlsxExporter xlsEexporter = new JRXlsxExporter();
xlsEexporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(print));
xlsEexporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(new File(xls_filePath)));
SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration config = new SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration();
xlsEexporter.setConfiguration(config);
xlsEexporter.exportReport();

/*Doc File Generation */
JRDocxExporter docxExporter = new JRDocxExporter();
docxExporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(print));
docxExporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(new File(doc_filePath)));
SimpleDocxReportConfiguration config = new SimpleDocxReportConfiguration();
docxExporter.setConfiguration(config);
docxExporter.exportReport();
```

How can I solve this problem? What I need to do configuration `SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration` and `SimpleDocxReportConfiguration`?;

Comment: Can you share jrxml files to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Its all about intend. In pdf all thing work good but for doc and excel you need to provide correct alignment for all element. If you post your jrxml file it will give me better understanding of code.